# Search in Kibana search bar

Tags: kibana

I'm looking to the logs in Kibana. I add this query to a search bar:

> "com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand"

And see 100000+ log records that contains this line.

Next I enter

> "HystrixCommand"

I expect to see even more logs than for `"com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand"` but there's nothing. Why?

Comment: Try **HystrixCommand** without the quotes.

Comment: I tried, no results with or without quotes